# Reorg of index for InstancePromotedPropertiesTable fails

Tags: sql-server-2008, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

At a customer where I have deployed an application that is using Workflow Services hosted in AppFabric and we persist the workflows in an instance store in SQL Server 2008. When they run their jobs to reorganize the indexes in the databases they get the following error message:

> Failed:(-1073548784) Executing the
>   query "ALTER INDEX
>   [CIX_InstancePromotedPropertiesTable]
>   ..." failed with the following error:
>   "The index
>   "CIX_InstancePromotedPropertiesTable"
>   (partition 1) on table
>   "InstancePromotedPropertiesTable"
>   cannot be reorganized because page
>   level locking is disabled.". Possible
>   failure reasons: Problems with the
>   query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set
>   correctly, or connection not
>   established correctly.

I recall having seen an explanation for this, but I cannot find it any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER INDEX [CIX_InstancePromotedPropertiesTable] ON [dbo].[InstancePromotedPropertiesTable] SET (
ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
) ;

hope this works

Comment: Actually I was wrong that this was a problem. The index is correct and I have told the customer to use rebuild instead of reorganize. Your solution is correct that i will solve the reorg problem, but this index should not be changed.